# Accessing Managed Class through Native C++ Plugin

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I have a native application which has a native C++ plugin framework that I would like to be able to talk to Managed classes.

In the past I have taken native calls using C++/CLI but I've never had to deal with returning C++/CLI/Managed code back to pure native code.

The most basic API that I have to implement here takes on the form of:

```
extern "C"  cppPlugin *CreatePlugin(void);                                      
extern      cppPlugin *pluginPtr;
```

What I would like is to be able to implement `cppPlugin` using managed code.  What are my options here?

Should I write a simple native proxy class in C++/CLI which makes the calls to the managed class or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I write a simple native proxy class in C++/CLI which makes the calls to the managed class or is there a better way?

That is typically the best way.  The `cppPlugin` pointer is a pointer to a native class, so you'll need to implement a native proxy for the managed data, and return that.